# Postgres ODBC driver module

Tags: postgresql, powershell, odbc

Overall problem is: I need to connect to Postgres DB from PowerShell. 
I found, that I need to install ODBC driver first. However, I need my script to be redistributable to different machines and a I cannot afford to install ODBC everywhere. Isn't there some kind of PowerShell ODBC module which I would simply import into PS session and I could use it to connect to DB? Thanks.

Comment: Does Postgres not have .NET connector?

Comment: @PetSerAl: yes it does: http://www.npgsql.org/

Comment: I got here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e1e03c3057aa997f33b. I had to download Npgsql package via nuget and load *.dll assembly into PS session. However, I can find any examples how to proceed next. What kind of methods are available in assembly and so on. Get-Member cmdlet is no help here :-(. Any ideas guys?

Comment: @MatthewLowe Do you work with any other ADO.NET provider before?

Comment: Absolutely not. My first time working with DB on .NET platform, including PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the comments you can do these sorts of things (using PS 3.0 features):

```
# List assemblies loaded
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies()

# May have to tweak 2nd argument to -like
$asm= [appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | ? name -like *npgssql* 

# look at all the types in the assembly
$asm.gettypes() | out-gridview

# Pick a class that looks interesting, filter it out
$typeToExamine = $asm.gettypes() | ? name -like *whateverlooksinteresting*

$typeToExamine.getproperties()|select name
# or alternatively
$typeToExamine.getproperties()|out-gridview

# similarly with $typeToExamine.getmethods()

# Or an alternative to getMethods()/getProperties() is to create an instance
# of the type and use get-member
```